# Using Regex in MySQL WHERE clauses under specific conditions

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Essentially, I'm working on a PHP-Based CMS and I'm looking to add an additional layer of security for the plugin infrastructure. Currently authors must secure their SQL clauses using traditional means, which is no problem.

The CMS accepts queries in seperate parts, and the WHERE clause is one part. As an added layer of security, what I would like to do is, before the WHERE clause is added to the statement, for the system to do a quick regex check to ensure the clause is valid.

The where clause is already has it's formula surrounded by brackets, so what I think would do it is simply ensuring...

- There's an equal number of brackets outside of quotations
- There are no hanging quotation marks
- The first bracket is not a closing bracket
- The last bracket is not an opening bracket
- There are no comments

Remember, this is just an added layer in case a plugin author forgets his coffee and doesn't sanitize his inputs. Does this sound like a sane solution? And are there any regex statements that are similar to what I described? It's the one thing I'm terrible at.

Comment: +1: Sanitizing user supplied SQL is not for the faint of heart

Answer (score 0):

I say, why not? Belts and braces away! I'd still rather provide an API over a letting them submit queries in part or in whole. This would allow you to use parameterized queries (prepared statements).

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about detecting syntax errors, such queries should fail when being parsed and never get run, so the data is safe. i doubt you'll ever find a regex or other tool that does as good a job as mysql itself and that will never give false negatives. shouldn't you be more concerned about returning meaningful debugging error messages from mysql?

if you're worried about input being unsanitised then you're not making it quick and easy enough to escape parameters. it only takes one decent function to translate *any* php variable into a safe mysql literal. drill into those authors that they must use that function for *every* parameter. e.g. a db class method:

```
final function esc($val) {
    if ($val === null)
        return 'NULL';
    if (is_bool($val))
        return $val ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    if (is_int($val) || is_float($val) || (is_string($val) && $val === (string) (int) $val))
        return $val;
    if (is_object($val) || is_array($val))
        $val = serialize($val);
    else
        $val = (string) $val;
    if (strlen($val)) {
        if ($this->real_esc)
            $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val, $this->cnn);
        else
            $val = mysql_escape_string($val);
    }
    return "'$val'";
}
```

where `$this->real_esc = function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string');` is done already for performance.